# SOOT ForwardFlowanalysis

Tags: java, soot

I am new to soot, and I started to write a class which extends `ForwardFlowAnalysis`. In my main function, I want to new a `ForwardFlowAnalysis` obj by using a constructor. But seems like the constructor is not executed for some reason, as a result only "1" is printed out. Anybody knows what is going on?

```java
public class MyMain{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PackManager.v().getPack("jtp").add(
            new Transform("jtp.myTransform", new BodyTransformer() {
                protected void internalTransform(Body body, String phase, Map options) {
                    G.v().out.println("1");
                    new MyAnalysis(new ExceptionalUnitGraph(body));
                    G.v().out.println("3");
}}));

    soot.Main.main(args);
}


public static class MyAnalysis extends ForwardFlowAnalysis  {
    public MyAnalysis(ExceptionalUnitGraph g) {
        super(g);
        G.v().out.println("2");
        doAnalysis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: Hmm, makes no sense to me. I think this should just work. Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I tried eclipse debugger before. It works now. I executed my soot analysis as a eclipse plugin before, now I added configurations within my main() function, and run soot analysis as a java application. I think there is something wrong about eclipse configuration for soot.